# C++ map::find for pair as key

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stdmap, std-pair

I have a map of pair as key and bool as value. When i try to find a certain pair that is already included using map::find method, it's not finding any item. What do i do wrong?

I tried to implement a comparator class and set it as key_comp in map, but I'm not sure i did it right. Is this the solve?

I am working in VS12, I attached a photo with the debugging, you shall understand much more from that:

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the **relevant** code instead of an image of it. Also _"it fails"_ is pretty vague. Does it find the wrong item or is it not finding an item at all?

Comment: not finding an item at all. in my opinion there's no point in including more code.. i will, but i don't think it will help you more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `find` with `pair<char *, char*>(0x00ffc468, 0x00ffbdb0)`. There is no such pair in the set, so `find` returns `end`.

Your code compares `char *`'s, which checks if they point to the same place in memory, not whether they point to identical content. You should probably use `std::string` instead of `char *` rather than reinventing wheels.

Here's an example of a possible comparison function you could use if you insist on doing so:

```
bool less(
    std::pair<char *, char *> const& p1,
    std::pair<char *, char *> const& p2)
{
    int i = strcmp (p1.first, p2.first);
    if (i < 0)
        return true;
    if (i > 0)
        return false;
    return strcmp (p1.second, p2.second) < 0;
}
```

Comment: can you suggest me an approach to solving it with char*, though?

Comment: You could write your own implementation of the comparison function that `map` needs for comparison and equality testing, but that would be a huge mistake, IMO.

Comment: If you happen to know what comparison functions i should implement, that would be great, else i will take the approach to changing to strings.

Comment: @RaduVlad He has a pair of `char *`'s.

Comment: tried this: 
class compareCharPair
{
public:
    bool operator()( pair<char*,char*> p1, pair<char*,char*> p2 )
    {
  return strcmp(p1.first,p2.first) < 0 && strcmp(p1.second,p2.second) < 0;
    }
};

but it fails

Comment: @RaduVlad Yeah, that logic is wrong. See my link above. You only want to compare the second strings if the first strings are equal!

Comment: i think that worked, will set the answer after i test it more. Thanks. Also, thanks for not making me post more code as it wouldn't have been relevant at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use `std:pair<char*, char*>` as key in your map, you can use the following functor while creating the map.

```
struct MyCompare
{
   bool operator()(std::pair<char const*, char const*> const& lhs,
                   std::pair<char const*, char const*> const& rhs)
   {
      int n1 = strcmp(lhs.first, rhs.first);
      if ( n1 != 0 )
      {
         return n1 < 0;
      }
      return (strcmp(lhs.second, rhs.second) < 0);
   }
};


typedef std::map<std::pair<char*,char*>, int, MyCompare> MyMap;
MyMap myMap;
```